# Where to find a HTML dictionary

Tags: html, documentation

I'm looking for some document, or website, where I can find **EVERYTHING** about HTML. Something like an HTML Dictionary/Encyclopedia. I want to read about the most unknown tags, attributes, and structures of this markup language. I've been looking for a document or a website, but I can't find any. Does someone know where I can find like a 'full documentation page' or something like that?

I'm looking for something like **official documentation**, not a course in Udemy or a Youtube video. I'm looking for just text and text about this markup language.

Can someone help me?

Comment: [One](https://devdocs.io/html/) [Two](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) [Three](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp)

Comment: And of course, [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/). Note: I strongly recommend not using tomerpacific's third link, w3schools is not nearly as reliable and accurate as MDN or (of course) the specification.

Comment: you can find what you need here https://www.w3schools.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many places for ***HTML*** and **Web Dev** reference, *some* of the common and *good* ones are listed below:-

1. [w3Schools](https://w3schools.com)
2. [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/)
3. [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)
4. [Dev Docs](https://devdocs.io)

These should be sufficient for your needs in HTML and other programming languages.
Note: None of these are HTML specific, or documentation specific, some of them are also learning platforms. Look around in these websites for references and resources alike.

Comment: Possibly all but w3schools. Still a poor resource for beginners due to many issues with code and recommendations